# Create Replica Sets on an existing sharded MongoDB

Tags: replication, mongodb, sharding

How do I convert an existing mongodb instance that has sharding enabled for some of its collections to a replica set? I am able to do it the other way around, but I am not able to figure out how to add replication to existing sharded mongo instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't convert collections to a replica set. You convert (stand alone shard) node (where all databases and collections are) to the replica set.

Convert (stand alone) node to the replica set, follow [these instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-standalone-to-replica-set/).

Comment: Thank you. So it looks like in my case I need to do a two stage process where I first convert the sharded cluster to a non sharded Replica Set (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-sharded-cluster-to-replica-set/) and then go from a non sharded Replica Set to a sharded Replica Set (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/convert-replica-set-to-replicated-shard-cluster/)